# When does java.util.Timer's background thread terminate after the task queue is empty?

Tags: java, timer

In java.util.Timer's documentation, it says:

> After the last live reference to a Timer object goes away and all outstanding tasks have completed execution, the timer's task execution thread terminates gracefully (and becomes subject to garbage collection).

But when I use the Timer to execute a one time task:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println("Timer is running");
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

After execution, the main thread does not terminate. But it can normally terminate when cancelled the timer explicitly like below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println("Timer is running");
        }
    }, 2000);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    timer.cancel();
}
```

After execution the task queue is empty and there are no more task to execute, yet the thread is not terminated. A thread dump shows:

```
"Timer-0" prio=5 tid=0x00007ff184046000 nid=0x5807 in Object.wait() [0x000000011ebea000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)  
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)  
- waiting on <0x00000007ab1bbea0> (a java.util.TaskQueue)  
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)  
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:526)  
- locked <0x00000007ab1bbea0> (a java.util.TaskQueue)  
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

The timer background thread is still WAITING. What's going on here?

Comment: But its the expected behaviour, as the javadoc mentioned. The same paragraph says "However, this can take arbitrarily long to occur. By default, the task execution thread does not run as a daemon thread, so it is capable of keeping an application from terminating. If a caller wants to terminate a timer's task execution thread rapidly, the caller should invoke the timer's cancel method."

Comment: @MikanMu What's the point of the question? Why did you not post the rest of the javadoc paragraph which explains what you're asking about?